# how do I fix this LEFT JOIN query?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

- products (product_id, title)
- comments (comment_id, product_id, user_id, comment, post_date)
- bookmarks (user_id, product_id, read_date)

For each product_id in the products table, I wish to retrieve the number of comments with the same product_id, and whose post_date value is greater than the read_date value for the row in the bookmarks table that shares this product_id, and has user_id=22.

If such a row does not exist in the bookmarks table, I want to retrieve the total number of comments for that product_id regardless of read_date.

So far I have

```
SELECT p.product_id, COUNT( c.comment_id ) comment_count
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN bookmarks b, comments c ON b.product_id = c.product_id
AND b.user_id =22
AND (
c.post_date > b.read_date
)
AND p.product_id = c.product_id
GROUP BY c.product_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

This does not give me the expected results. How can I modify it to make it do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you ?

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
COUNT(CASE 
  WHEN b.read_date IS NOT NULL AND c.post_date >b.read_date THEN c.comment_id
  WHEN b.read_date IS NULL THEN c.comment_id
  ELSE NULL //optional, CASE has default ELSE NULL
END) as comment_count
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN bookmarks b ON (b.product_id = p.product_id AND b.user_id=22) 
LEFT JOIN comments c ON (p.product_id = c.product_id)
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

**UPDATE**
`GROUP BY c.product_id` changed to `GROUP BY p.product_id`

Comment: It looks like there is still something going on. Your query gives me 4 rows of results on a product table of about 475K rows. The comment_count value is also incorrect (I am getting three comment counts of 0, and one comment count of 1, when there are several products with multiple comments).

Comment: actually the comment_count values are correct, I made a mistake in evaluating them. Would it be correct to GROUP BY p.product_id instead of c.product_id?

Comment: if 'nullable' means that they can be NULL, then no, they always have a date value. (Let me know if I have misunderstood the question.)

Comment: @jela: Yeah, it's what I meant when asking about nullability. I hope the query will work for you

Comment: thanks it looks like it's working great, and I also learned about the CASE syntax. I was wondering if you can suggest what columns I should index to make it faster (right now it's 2.65 seconds for 500k product rows, with less than 20 comment rows and bookmark rows respectively). right now I have a primary index on products.product_id, indexes on bookmarks.bookmark_id and bookmarks.user_id, primary index on comments.comment_id, and indexes on comments.user_id and comments.product_id.

Comment: This query should also benefit from index on  (`bookmarks.product_id,bookmarks.user_id`)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you or atleast point you in the right direction.

```
SELECT p.product_id COUNT( c.comment_id ) comment_count
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN comments c on c.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN bookmarks b on b.product_id = c.product_id
WHERE (p.product_id IN (
  SELECT *
  FROM bookmarks b
  WHERE b.user_id = 22
 )
 AND
 c.post_date > b.read_date
)
OR
p.product_id NOT IN (
 SELECT *
 FROM bookmarks b
 WHERE b.user_id = 22
)
GROUP BY c.product_id
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```